# parse NSDate and save in xcdatamodel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdate

I have an UNIHTTPJsonResponse object.. one property is a Date and I must save this date in my local entity (NSDate)...

```
    NSDictionary *myObject;
    NSDictionary *guildInformation = response.body.JSONObject;

    if ([[guildInformation objectForKey:@"result"] boolValue]) {
        NSArray *myArray = [guildInformation objectForKey:@"plates"];
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.count; i++) {
            myObject = myArray[i];

            NSDate *date = [targaServ objectForKey:@"date"];

            NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"];
            NSDate *date2 = [fmt dateFromString:[myObject objectForKey:@"date"]];

            [self myFunct:[myObject objectForKey:@"plate"]
                                user: [guildInformation objectForKey:@"user"]
                              inDate: date]; //or date2
        }
    }
```

with date give me an error:

> Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "dataIns";
>   desired type = NSDate; given type = __NSCFString

with the second test, date2 is null... how can I parse my date for my NSDate and my entity?

Comment: what value of date you are getting from server ?

Comment: I have my n records with a date property... this happens in remote server... I need to import those records in my local entity, when I log in my app...

Comment: you are using this code to convert from nsstring to nsdate
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"];
            NSDate *date2 = [fmt dateFromString:[myObject objectForKey:@"date"]];
I am sure date2 can't be nil check that what you are getting in it using
NSstring *str = [myObject objectForKey:@"date"];
I think your input string is nil

Comment: no no... I tried this! the string is right... but if I try to set a NSDate, give me nil! I read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: and I see deprecat all init method with string!! there are only initWithTimeInterval! How I calculate this!?!

Comment: Look if you are getting some thing like 1213242343253 from server then you can use this code NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];////timestamp=1213242343253 mostly you get date from server in time stamp like this

Comment: I tried... with timestamp = 1213242343253.. and save my record in my local entity!! and my app works... the real problem is convert date in my response!!! it's a insert date... it's important!

Comment: can you print here date in string from server ? so that I can convert it and give back to you

Comment: this is my log: "data:2015-01-19 15:56:53" but .... I need to convert method for all dates...

Comment: in your code change line to this [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"]; will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple bug. If you had turned on warnings, the compiler would have told you that you are not using date2. That should be a hint. I would bet that date is not an NSDate at all.

And note that the format in the NSDateFormatter must match the actual string.

Comment: date in response is a String... in this format: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss but when i try [fmt dateFromString:[myObject objectForKey:@"date"]] return me value = nil! I don't know why!